# How can I create multiple BEFORE INSERT triggers?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to learn mysql more in depth with relationships, triggers and what not. I currently have these 2 triggers for my database:

[image]

I'm trying to add another one that will `BEFORE INSERT` a different `table`

[image]

But I keep getting this error:
[image]

I'm not sure how I can get around this, or if this is specific to Sequel Pro (The GUI I'm using), it seems to wrap the query internally so I only have to enter the basic stuff, is there any way I can get this to work? My schema is like:

`Forum_Threads` has many `Forum_Posts`

`Forum_Posts` has many `Posts_Replies`

`Forum_Threads` and `Forum_Posts` both have a reply counter, so I'm trying to increment / decrement the `reply_count` on both tables when I'm inserting or deleting replies. Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105578/error-this-version-of-mariadb-doesnt-yet-support-multiple-triggers-with-the-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to 'create' multiple BEFORE INSERT triggers, but a possible workaround for you would be setting a behavior for each type of event.

Something like this may help you:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `<your_trigger>`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `<your_trigger>` BEFORE INSERT ON `<your_table>`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CASE <your_identifier>
        WHEN <first_type> THEN
            /*
                ACTION BLOCK
                FOR THIS EVENT
            */
        WHEN <second_type> THEN
            /*
                ACTION BLOCK
                FOR THIS EVENT
            */
        ELSE
            /*
                ACTION BLOCK
                FOR THIS EVENT
            */
    END;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You can add as many event type as you needed, by doing this you can create a trigger that has multiple action based on a given event type identifier.

I hope this can help you, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the GUI is trying to do a `create trigger` on a table that already has a before insert type trigger. Check your "Forum_threads" table to see if there's a BEFORE UPDATE trigger already on it.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to MySQL 5.7.2,

> There cannot be multiple triggers for a given table that have the same
>   trigger event and action time. For example, you cannot have two BEFORE
>   UPDATE triggers for a table. But you can have a BEFORE UPDATE and a
>   BEFORE INSERT trigger, or a BEFORE UPDATE and an AFTER UPDATE trigger.

(see [13.1.19 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) from the 5.6 manual.)

You can, however, specify multiple actions within the body of a given trigger, although the one-trigger-per-event limit can make managing trigger actions inconvenient.